# Linq To Entities Where Condition to Expressions comparison

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression

I have 3 classes mapped with Entity Framework

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have this Linq To Entities Where Condition

```
return queryableOfB.Where(b => b.A.Name = instanceOfC.Name);
```

Because this is a repetitive method in my logic, I want to create a method as:

```
protected void GetFilter<B, TBProperty, TCProperty>(
        IQueryable<B> queryofB, C cModel, 
        Expression<Func<B, TBProperty>> bExpression,
        Expression<Func<C, TCProperty>> cExpression)
    {
        var bExpValue = cExpression.Compile()(cModel);
        queryofB.Where(b => b.Property.EndsWith(bExpValue)); // How can I compare two expressions? but adding "for example" an .EndsWith to expression 1?
    }
```

It's important not to pass the .EndsWith in the expression because the decision of using EndsWith, StartsWith, Contains or exact comparison must be done in the method.

Thank you in advance Gurus.

Comment: It's definitely possible, yes. You'll need to do something like `var methodCall = Expression.Method(typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith"), bExpression, cExpression);` and then `queryofB.Where(methodCall);`. You'll need to tweak that (haven't tested it locally), but it should give you a head start, and at the very least, there are plenty of SO questions asking for the same thing which you might find by searching for "C# Expression Builder Entity Framework"

Comment: Thanks @Rob, static Expression.Method ??? doesn't exists

Comment: actually `where ` method expect predicate on function. you can try with predicate

Answer (score 0):

actually `where` method expect function as predicate. you can try with below one.

**its doing nothing just calling the where Extension method.  its better to use there where method inline.  But telling u the way how can u  do it.**

```
  static IEnumerable<T1> M<T1>(IEnumerable<T1> objEnumerable, Func<T1, bool> wherePredicate)
  {
      return objEnumerable.Where(predicate);
  }

  // calling like 
  var listOfBObjects = GetBObjectIEnumerable();
  C instanceOfC  = GetCClassObject();
  M<B>(listOfBObjects, b => b.A.Name = instanceOfC.Name);
```

**update**

you can use the

```
  M<B>(listOfBObjects, b => b.A.Name.Equals(instanceOfC.Name));
  M<B>(listOfBObjects, b => b.A.Name.StartsWith(instanceOfC.Name));
  M<B>(listOfBObjects, b => b.A.Name.Contains(instanceOfC.Name));
```

to improve the performance and all. yes you can use the `IQueryable` rather than `IEnumerable`

Comment: the comparison you're using in the predicate is by equality, in this context I don't know if I will use EndsWith, StartsWith, Contains or exact comparison, this will be determined into the M<T1> method.

Comment: Using IQueryable<T> as return value and as type of objEnumerable will probably perform better because the where clause will be executed directly on the DB after all extension methods have been applied. But beware of using a wherePredicate that can not be translated into SQL, e.g. because it calls C# code like .Equals() or .ToString().

Comment: @Manu you can use the starts with, endsWith , Contains here as well.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider, the condition b => b.Property.EndsWith(bExpValue) will be composed inside the method, my concern is about joining b => b.Prop "and" c => c.Prop into something like b.Prop.EndsWith(argument); "where argument is a compiled value".

Comment: here i already told method `M` is nothing, just calling the `where ` extension method thats it. so better to include the `where` inline. but you can use the approach as per the need.